# How do I fix the cv.imwrite to that I don't get an error, and a copy of the images saves in my desired folder

Tags: windows, opencv, google-colaboratory

(Beginner)

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

lena.jpg(image/jpeg) - 91814 bytes, last modified: n/a - 100% done

Saving lena.jpg to lena.jpg

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', 0)

print(img)

cv2_imshow(img)

cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/borby/Desktop/image',img)
```

The output shows the image matrices and the image, but after, I receive this error:

> error Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>         5 cv2_imshow(img)
>         6 
>   ----> 7 cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/borby/Desktop/image',img)
>
> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:661: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'

How do I fix it so a copy of img saves in the image folder?

Comment: it should be cv2.imshow("image",img)

Comment: The issue is with the cv2.imwrite, not imshow. The reason it is not cv2.imshow is because that does not work on Google Colab, instead it was patched and you now use cv_imshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working on Google colab you are working on a virtual machine. So basically you cannot access your desktop files straight away and that is why you used `files.upload` in the first place, instead of just specifying the path of the image.

So just write:

```
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg',img)
```

Now you can access it on the left side and download it from there or you can add this code:

```
files.download('image.jpg')
```